# Any way to mount a directory from entrypoint script?

Tags: docker

I have my docker run like this as of now

```
docker run  -v $HOME:/home/$USER --entrypoint startup.sh -it myimage
```

I would like to wrap the mounting part -v $HOME:/home/$USER in the startup.sh script, if possible. Can this be done?

The goal is to have our team just do docker run with entry point.

Answer (score 0):

No. Docker can't mount a volume after it starts. Seems like you would want to use [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to set up your volumes, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, etc., then you could have your team simply run `docker-compose up`.

You could also use a shell script but in any case, using Compose is going to give you more flexibility in your project even if you start with only one container.